# Windows screen started to blink when login user

Tags: login-screen

I login my Windows 10, the screen started to blink after a few seconds.

I have only 1 user login.

I tried to repair my pc with Windows installation CD.

The startup repair was failed. No system restore able to find and cannot find a system image to be restored.

Anyway to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

upgrade with windows upgrade media tool

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.